# Numerical solution of fractional integro-diffrential equ. using collocation method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, integral-equations, maple, integro-differential-equations

problem comes from 
"Numerical solution of fractional integro-differential , equations by collocation method , E.A. Rawashdeh, Department of Mathematics, Yarmouk University, Irbid 21110, Jordan"

$D^qy(t)=p(t)y(t)+f(t)+\int_{0}^{1}{K(t,s)y(s)\,ds} , t\in I=[0,1]$

I want to create a maple code to check if the results in given article is valid or not but I do not have any idea about collocation method!

any reference to collocation method solution are welcome!

Comment: This question may be best posted on scicomp.stackexchange.com.  It is more geared towards numerical methods for scientific computing.

Comment: @Paul: thanks for your guide, I added there too but still there is no answer http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3296/numerical-solution-of-fractional-integro-diffrential-equ-using-collocation-meth

Answer (score 3):

See first how the collocation method is applied to simpler problems and then advance with your problem. See for example [here](http://homepages.rpi.edu/~suarep/Site/Numerical_Computing_files/Lecture15.pdf) where the method is applied to find the solution of a an ODE with boundary conditions. Here is [paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2157544) on collocation method for solving integral equations.

Comment: Great thanks @Mhenni Benghorbal it really helped me understand collocation method.